# Three.js - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scene')

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, three.js

Below is code to display a 3d stl model in a webapp. I am getting the title-mentioned error in the console and i cannot for the life of me figure out why... This code is situated in myModule.js in a static folder. It is called by main.js also in the static folder. In my html file, located in templates folder, it is being called once the stl files is successfully loaded using:

```
<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.module.js';
</script>
<script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.js') }}"></script>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
export function myFunction() {
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const uploadForm = document.getElementById("upload-form");
    const uploadStatus = document.getElementById("upload-status");
    const stlUploadUrl = document.getElementById("stl-upload-url");
    const stlCanvas = document.getElementById("stl-canvas");

    uploadForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const form = event.target;
        const formData = new FormData(form);

        fetch(form.action, {
            method: form.method,
            body: formData,
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json(); // Assuming your Flask route returns JSON data
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            uploadStatus.innerText = data.upload_status;
            stlUploadUrl.innerText = data.stl_upload;
            stlUploadUrl.style.display = "block";

            // Show the canvas after a successful upload
            stlCanvas.style.display = "block";

            // Get the URL of the uploaded STL file
            const stlUrl = data.stl_upload;

            // Load and display the STL file
            loadSTLFile(stlUrl);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    });

    function loadSTLFile(stlUrl) {
        // Create a scene
        // const scene = new THREE.Scene(); // declared in the global scope

        // Create a camera
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 5;

        // Create a renderer
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        stlCanvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // Load the STL file
        const loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
        loader.load(stlUrl, function (stl) {
            const mesh = stl.scene;
            scene.add(mesh);

            // Add interactivity for rotation and zoom
            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            // Render the scene
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }
            animate();
        });
    }
});
}
```

I have tried loading it from three, different versions and examples of three.js, with no luck. Note, I am new to this so please excuse me if it's a ridiculous question. I understand that i am meant to have the Three .js files located on a server. With this adjustment I am still having the same error.

Comment: You have the declaration of `scene` commented out. Once you've fixed that, you will also need to add lights to your scene before you will be able to see anything rendered.

Comment: sorry i forgot to meantion. scene is declared in the global scope. I will add lights and see the results thank you